# Setting ImageViews as button background failing

Tags: java, button, javafx, arraylist, imageview

Context: I'm creating a puzzle game as part of a project, I've finished the logic and just want to set backgrounds to my buttons.

The code using for creating BackgroundImages I found on here and while it sets the background every button receives the first element in the ImageView List.

Here is the result showing each button receiving element 0 in the ImageView List and below I displayed all 4 of the elements just to check I populated the ImageView List correctly.

[image: Image showing result]

```
List<Button> pieces = new ArrayList<>();
List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<>();
VBox layout = new VBox();
HBox original = new HBox();
Image image = new Image("jalter.png");  
HBox imagesList = new HBox();   



for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
  pieces.add(new Button(String.valueOf(i+1)));
  pieces.get(i).setPrefSize(150,150);  

  images.add(new ImageView(image));  
  images.get(i).setViewport(new Rectangle2D(
  getX(toGridXY(i)) * 150,
  getY(toGridXY(i)) * 150,
  150,
  150));    

  BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new                     
  BackgroundImage
  (images.get(i).getImage(), 
  BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, 
  BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, 
  BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, 
  BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);  
  Background background = new 
  Background(backgroundImage);      
  pieces.get(i).setBackground(background);      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the background of each one to a background with exactly the same image. `ImageView.getImage()` is just going to return the original image you passed; it's not going to crop that image to the viewport of the image view.

Instead, you can create a new `Image` using the `pixelReader` of the original image, and providing a cropping region in the constructor of `WritableImage`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
  Button button = new Button(String.valueOf(i+1));
  pieces.add(button);
  button.setPrefSize(150,150);  

  Image croppedImage = new WritableImage(image.getPixelReader(),
    getX(toGridXY(i)) * 150,
    getY(toGridXY(i)) * 150,
    150,
    150);

  BackgroundImage backgroundImage = new BackgroundImage(
    croppedImage,
    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, 
    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, 
    BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT, 
    BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);  
  Background background = new Background(backgroundImage);      
  button.setBackground(background);      
}
```

Comment: Thank you James, I didn't understand what getImage() was doing.